# How do I change the column of Buttons, when being made by command?

Tags: python, tkinter, lambda

I'm making buttons from a list on a command and I was wondering how I can make it so after a certain number of buttons it starts creating buttons on a different column?

For example:

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

def func(number):
    some_function()

for number in list:
    button = Button(root, text=number, command=lambda x=number: func(x))
    button.grid()
```

So after say 5 buttons made I was wondering if I could make it to continue making buttons on the second column?

After trying to find an answer I was unsuccessful so any help is much appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate the row and column using the index of the item in the list and `divmod()` function.  Also better don't use keyword `list` as the variable name.

```py
# don't use keyword list as variable name
itemlist = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

def func(number):
    some_function()

for idx, number in enumerate(itemlist):
    col, row = divmod(idx, 5) # change 5 to other value to suit your case
    button = Button(root, text=number, command=lambda x=number: func(x))
    button.grid(row=row, column=col)
```